# Configure Yahoo mail account to Windows Phone 8 or any app for that

Tags: email, accounts

We are unable to configure my Yahoo e-mail in Outlook for Windows 8 Phone. Please give us any concrete solution.

Comment: Please share more details like screenshots, what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't be simplier, Simply go to **Settings** -> **email+accounts** And tap **add an account**, choosing **Yahoo! Mail** from the account type list